# Why $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] returns 127.0.0.1 instead of public IP?

Tags: php, server, ip, localhost

It is very confusing for me why on localhost my IP address is `127.0.0.1` ? That has to be the server IP, not the client IP? When I run my website I run it as a user, right?

Comment: If you're on your localhost your server address will be 127.0.0.1. Your server *is* remote from your browser even if they are on the same computer.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP manual says

> "REMOTE_ADDR" => The IP address from which the user is viewing the
>   current page.

You are currently viewing the page from `localhost` i.e `127.0.0.1`, simple.

Comment: But how I am viewing it from localhost? I just point to localhost to open the page. If I go to google.com , that doesn't mean that I open google from the google host. It's kinda confusing.

Comment: IP address "from which" the user is viewing. You are viewing it from google's hosted machine not your machine.